# Ember JS: Assertion Failed: `AdapterError` expects json-api formatted errors array

Tags: ember.js, json-api

I am making my first Ember/Phoenix app using JSONAPIAdapter. When doing a post request Ember responds with `Assertion Failed: AdapterError expects json-api formatted errors array.`

Below is the relevant code:

adapter/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
import DataAdapterMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/data-adapter-mixin';
import config from '../config/environment';

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend(DataAdapterMixin, {

});
```

serializers/application.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({

});
```

request payload:

```
{
    "data": {
        "attributes": {
            "name": ""
        },
        "relationships": {
            "user": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "users",
                    "id": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        "type": "listings"
    }
}
```

response payload:

```
{"errors":{"name":["can't be blank"]}}
```

Why does Ember keeps giving me this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response payload is not correct. You are using **json-api**. So your payloads have to follow the [**json-api** specification](http://jsonapi.org/). Your request-payload looks correct. But check out how errors have to be [serialized](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors). 
A json-api error response must contain a root key **"errors"** holding an array of error-objects. Regarding the [documenation](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors) an error may contain several members, but the two most important are **detail** and **source**.

Here's an example:

```
{
  "errors":[
    {
       "detail": "can't be blank",
       "source": {
         "pointer": "data/attributes/name"
       }
    }
  ]
}
```

The **source**-key contains a json-object holding a json-api-pointer. With the help of this **pointer** information ember's JSONAPI-Adapter adds the errors to the corresponding attributes of your record. Note that your backend needs to send a **422 HTTP status code** (Unprocessable Entity).

If that works you can do something like that at client:

```
{{#each model.errors.name as |error|}}
  <div class="error">
    {{error.message}}
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

How do you serialize your errors at backend? Are you using [ja_serializer](https://github.com/vt-elixir/ja_serializer)? If not, I would recommend it, because ja_serializer can serialize json-api-errors by default.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://jsonapi.org/format/#errors) already linked by wuarmin clearly states (capitals theirs, italics mine):

> Error objects MUST be returned as an *array* keyed by errors

Your API response' `errors` key has a single object as value, not an array.